# How to add vertical border in HTML like in image

Tags: html, css

[image: Sample Image]

I want help on how can i create vertical border like in in sample image.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CSS Grid
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

I wrote this code to show you how would be look grid on your template website

```css
.item1 { grid-area: header; }
.item2 { grid-area: left; }
.item3 { grid-area: main; }
.item4 { grid-area: right; }
.item5 { grid-area: footer; }

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'left header header header header right'
    'left main main main main right'
    'left footer footer footer footer right';
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 7px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">Header</div>
  <div class="item2">Left</div>
  <div class="item3">Main</div>  
  <div class="item4">Right</div>
  <div class="item5">Footer</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```